# How to remove the first and last character of a string?

Tags: java, string

I have worked in a SOAP message to get the LoginToken from a Webservice, and store that LoginToken as a String. U used `System.out.println(LoginToken);` to print the value. This prints `[wdsd34svdf]`, but I want only `wdsd34svdf`. How can I remove these square brackets at the start and end of the output?

Example:

```
String LoginToken=getName().toString();
System.out.println("LoginToken" + LoginToken);
```

The output is: `[wdsd34svdf]`.

I want just `wdsd34svdf`

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You need to find the index of `[` and `]`  then `substring`. (Here `[` is always at start and `]` is at end):

```
String loginToken = "[wdsd34svdf]";
System.out.println( loginToken.substring( 1, loginToken.length() - 1 ) );
```

Comment: This should be loginToken.length()-2 to remove the end bracket.

Comment: @mga911  As I mentioned in my answer, the 'substring(beginIndex,endIndex)' parameter should be '1' and 'loginToken.length()-1' respectively ( index of [ and ] ). The first parameter is inclusive and the second parameter is exclusive.
Above code gives me the correct output.

Comment: i use `(error.substring(2, error.length()-1))` to remove first and last brackets!

Answer (score 32):

This is generic solution:

```
str.replaceAll("^.|.$", "")
```

Answer (score 17):

You can always use `substring`:

```
String loginToken = getName().toString();
loginToken = loginToken.substring(1, loginToken.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 9):

Another solution for this issue is use commons-lang (since version 2.0) `StringUtils.substringBetween(String str, String open, String close)` method. Main advantage is that it's null safe operation.

```
StringUtils.substringBetween("[wdsd34svdf]", "[", "]"); // returns wdsd34svdf
```

Comment: This will work for that specific scenario, but would return "wdsd" if "[wdsd]34svdf]" was passed as the first parameter.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar scenario, and I thought that something like

```
str.replaceAll("\[|\]", "");
```

looked cleaner. Of course, if your token might have brackets in it, that wouldn't work.

Comment: please note that only the replaceAll() and replaceFirst() supports the regex, so here str.replaceAll("\\\[|\\\]", ""); will work

Comment: The correct expression is something like str = str.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""); see the missing \\ in your expression

Answer (score 5):

Try this to remove the first and last bracket of string ex.[1,2,3]

```
String s =str.replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "");
```

Exptected result = 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

This way you can remove 1 leading "[" and 1 trailing "]" character. If your string happen to not start with "[" or end with "]" it won't remove anything:

```
str.replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "")
```

Comment: Have you tested that? I may be wrong, but it looks like "start of string, then either [ or ] then end of string". Don't we need brackets here?

Comment: Yeah, it works perfectly fine:
     @Test
 public void testReplace(){
  String str = "[wdsd34svdf]";
  str = str.replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "");
  assertTrue(str.equals("wdsd34svdf"));
 }

Answer (score 1):

this is perfectly working fine

```java
String str = "[wdsd34svdf]";
//String str1 = str.replace("[","").replace("]", "");
String str1 = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
System.out.println(str1);


String strr = "[wdsd(340) svdf]";
String strr1 = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
System.out.println(strr1);
```

Comment: I think there's a typo on the next to last line in the code. I think you meant to say `strr.replaceAll(...)` instead of `str.replaceAll(...)`  (Replace **str** with **strr**)

Answer (score 0):

`StringUtils`'s `removeStart` and `removeEnd` method help to remove string from start and end of a string.

In this case we could also use combination of this two method

```
String string = "[wdsd34svdf]";
System.out.println(StringUtils.removeStart(StringUtils.removeEnd(string, "]"), "["));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin

```
private fun removeLastChar(str: String?): String? {
    return if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) str else str.substring(0, str.length - 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Remove the First and Last character in string in JAVA**
first to get a string, use substring method to print.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String str=sc.next();
System.out.println(str.substring(1,a.length()-1));
```

Answer (score -1):

**This will gives you basic idea**

```
    String str="";
    String str1="";
    Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    str=S.nextLine();
    int length=str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        str1=str.substring(1, length-1);
    }
    System.out.println(str1);
```