# How to remove a character of a string within an arraylist<String>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an array list like this:
[name1, name2,name3]
When I put that in a spinner, it prints the name this way:

[image]

I need to remove the "[" in the first position of the array(so the first name) and the "]" in the last position of my array(so the last name).

that's my code:

```
//Extracting participants ArrayList from the document
                        for(Object item : task.getResult().getData().values()) {
                            String[] values = String.valueOf(item).split(",");

                           // values[1] = values[1].substring(1, values[1].length());
                            for (String value : values){

                                    partecipantsArrayList.add(value);

                            }
```

the line of code with the comment, doesn't work.

Comment: String.valueOf(item).remove("[",""),remove("]","").split(",");

Comment: Is that a list of which you are using a default `toString` implementation?

Comment: [Use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846173/how-to-remove-first-and-last-character-of-a-string) to remove the first and last character of a string, and do that _before_ you split it.

Comment: you can simple check if item instanceOf ArrayList than cast item to list. or if instanceOf Arrays convert item to arraylist

Comment: You can convert string into jsonarray then you can iterate and add item to arraylist..(There is no need to split anything)

Comment: Try this             List<String> values = String.valueOf(item).split(",");
                                    partecipantsArrayList.addAll(values);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps

1. Remove `[` from your string

   ```
   values = values.replace('[',"");
   ```
2. Remove `]` from your string

   ```
   values = values.replace(']',"");
   ```
3. Then split the string with `,`.

Comment: What if the name (for whatever reason) contains a "[" or "]"?

Comment: Thank you, I modified the code this way: String[] values = String.valueOf(item).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(","); and now it works!

Comment: @Ivar yes that could be a problem..i force the user to use only alphabet character

Answer (score 1):

```
//Extracting participants ArrayList from the document
    for (Object item : task.getResult().getData().values()) {
        String itemToString = item.toString();
        itemToString = itemToString.subSequence(1, itemToString.length() - 1).toString();
        String[] values = itemToString.split(",");
        for (String value : values) {
            partecipantsArrayList.add(value);
        }
    }
```